# $\bar{d}(A)$=1, $\bar{d}(A-t)$=1, but how about $\bar{d}(A\cap A-t)$?

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory

$\bar{d}(A-t)$=1 because upper density will not be influenced by finite shift but how about their intersection will $\bar{d}(A\cap A-t)$ always be 1? (it may sound intuitively right, but any formal proof?) What about $\bar{d}(A)$=$\sigma$, 0<$\sigma$<1, what will happen to $\bar{d}(A\cap A-t)$?

Also similar question for the upper density of normal set B, $\bar{d}(B)$=1/2, $\bar{d}(B-t)$=1/2, then $\bar{d}(B\cap B-t)$=1/4, how can I use definition of upper density to write it as a proof formally?

Then, a general thought and conclusion that this kind of shifting and then trying to find the upper density of intersection of the original set and the shifted set is only meaningful for set with $\bar{d}$=1 or normal set with $\bar{d}$=1/2. But why???

Comment: Needs notation explained, also what has been assumed and what needs showing? [Looks in title d bar of A = 1 is assumed...]

Comment: @coffeemath, yes $\bar{d}(A)$=1 is assumed, and I know how to prove $\bar{d}(A-t)$=1 but $\bar{d}(A\cap A-t)$ needs showing. $\bar{d}$ means [upper density], (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_density)

Comment: If we take $B$ as the set of even numbers so $\bar d(B)=1/2$ then take $t=1$, we'd have $ B \cap (B-t) = \emptyset$ , wouldn't we? Or with $t=2$ no change.